# Display external pdf in frame with javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, frame

Exactly that. Can it be done? I.e. can I use javascript to load in a frame a pdf from an external website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can...

```
<iframe id="someFrame" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('someFrame').src = 'http://somesite.com/somefile.pdf';
</script>
```

Comment: @user2104778: What the browser _does_ with the data (in this case a PDF file) is entirely up to the browser.  This is true of any response from a web server, not just PDF files.  Does the PDF response include a `Content-disposition` header?  If so, then the server _wants_ it to be treated as a file and downloaded.  Overriding that would be a per-browser setting.

Comment: @user2104778: In FireFox you would change the setting in the Applications tab in the Options dialog.  For other browsers, I guess look for similar settings.  Each particular browser may not even expose such a setting, at least not in the interface.

Comment: Use a PHP code as webservice, that do the Content-disposition header and `file_get_contents` (ex. `src=my.php?pdf=http://somesite.com/somefile.pdf`)